# npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR! Could not install from "Ibrahi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\8992" as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm sitting my react environment and I get this error.

New react installation. `npm --version` is running correctly but still :

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
>
> npm ERR! Could not install from "Ibrahi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\8992" as it does not contain a package.json file.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 88):

I faced same issue, problem was due to space in my user name i.e. FirstName LastName and issue is with npx. I applied following fix and everything worked just fine

```
npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global
```

Source: https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146

Comment: you sir, are a savier, just got my nose out of this after 2h of researching.

Comment: @AndreiChivu you are most welcome, we all are here to help each other :)

Comment: @BhupenderKeswani whoever you are, I will upvote you.

Comment: @Bhupender Keswani Your answer worked for me when I wanted to [create a vue project](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#local)  with ```npm init vue@latest``` command. I had the same error in the question and your solution worked but I must change the directory to the address that ```npm-cache``` exist in my PC. For me that address is ```C:\Users\hamid davodi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache```.

Answer (score 15):

Many thanks to Bhupender for providing the github link!

A summary of the best answers there, for those, like me, coming late to the party:

Find the windows short name for your user directory...

```
cd C:\Users
dir /x
```

Then edit the npm cache location to use the windows short name.

e.g. "C:\Users\HP User" is also "C:\Users\HPUSER~1" so the following command resolves the problem...

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\HPUSER~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

This has the advantage of avoiding having to install create react app locally.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I just had to replace whitespace by ~1 but it's not quite. Have to run that first command dir /x on C:\Users to get the proper dir name without space. In my case, the name is "Gabriel Linassi". I wrote "Gabriel~1Linassi" but was rather "GABRIE~1"

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party but I was also facing the same issue so what I did is

1. Step 1:
   Open the Terminal as an Admin and run the following command first
   `npm install -g create-react-app` to get around the npx issue.
2. After step 1 run this command:- `npx create-react-app my-first-app`
   hope so it'll help you.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when you have a space in your path. To fix it follow these steps:

1. run `npm config edit`
2. go to line where cache is: `; cache = 'C:\Users\FIRSTNAME LASTNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache'`
3. replace the space between firstname and lastname with `~1`
4. remove `;` at the beginning of the line
5. run `yarn`

Just to make sure you've got it, the line should look like this:

`cache = 'C:\Users\FIRSTNAME~1LASTNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`

Comment: replacing spaces with ~1 worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to solve the problem:

1. run npm config edit command, then edit the line number 37.
2. Remove the coma(;) at the begining of the line and the space between
           Luxis and computers:

   - From this: ; cache=C:\Users\Luxis
     Computers\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache)
   - To this: cache=C:\Users\LuxisComputers\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Comment: not sure why you duplicated my answer here

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, and here is what worked for me.

1. I installed **create-react-app**, first using the command:
   `npm install -g create-react-app`
2. Then i created the react Application using:
   `npx create-react-app myfirstreact`

Comment: You save my day. Thank you very much <3

Comment: You're welcome @itTech. It's good to know that an age old solution still works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your CMD

npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global

https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146

Answer (score 0):

Simply, run:

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache"
```

Instead of `Omar` write the first name of your user's folder (in my case the folder name is Omar Sabri).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command issue will be sorted out.
It is due to space in the User Name.
npm config set cache "C:\Users\FirstName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache"

Answer (score 0):

nice remove the Spaces in file names,as npm config set cache "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache"